# Generate new random values and store in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I am trying to generate two random values and store them in an array however I would like them to be different values each time a random number between 0-3 is generated.

```
function new_Randomvalues(n) {
    var array1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var row = Math.round(3*Math.random());
        var col = Math.round(3*Math.random());
        array1.push([row,col]);
    }
    return array1;
}
console.log(new_Randomvalues(10));
```

How do I edit this function where if an array of same numbers are pushed into array1 then remove those and generate 10 unique coordinates.
Help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Each time you invoke this function, new random numbers are returned.

Comment: @Orius reread the question its quite clear

Comment: So you want the output array to only contain _unique_ combinations?

Comment: @Orius Yes but I want them to be different numbers such as if the function generates [0,0] then there shouldn't be another [0,0] and they should all be unique. Hope that clears up

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes exactly

Comment: @sam you can only ever have a maximum of 16 values.

Comment: Yes it is a 4x4 sudoku program and the values must not exceed 16

Comment: You can generate all possible pairs, put them in an array, shuffle it, and choose the first 10 entries. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Orius this may sound stupid but how do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: @James thanks. I will try and work on it

Comment: @sam See my answer (not the best use of the answer mechanism, but what can you do...)

Comment: @Orius I will give it a try. It seems to be working when I run it here. Thank you for much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per sam's question in the comments, here's the code:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}

pairs = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        pairs.push([i, j]);
    }
}

shuffle(pairs);

pairs = pairs.slice(0, 10);

console.log(pairs);
```